# PasswordType not supported in Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

In SQLAlchemy, when I try to query for user by 
`request.db.query(models.User.password).filter(models.User.email == email).first()`

Of course it works with different DB (SQLite3).
The source of the problem is, that the password is 
`sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy_utils.types.passwordPasswordType(schemes=['pbkdf2_sha512']), nullable=False)`

I really don't know how to solve it

I'm using `psycopg2`

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was a problem with Alembic migration, in migration table must be also created with the `PasswordType`, not `String` or any other type